# Pronterface window question

Tags: diy-3d-printer, firmware

I switched to a Raspberry Pi 3 to use with (Linux) Pronterface for my 3D printer.

This Pi 3 has a 3.5" 320x480 LCD display. When Pronterface is loaded, only part of its window can be seen and some of the UI elements are unreachable. I have the Pronterface source code from GitHub.

Where do I start to shrink the app window?

Answer (score 3):

You can change your Pi's resolution using `raspi-config` or the Raspberry Pi Configuration app.

To use `raspi-config`, access Terminal and run `raspi-config`. Then navigate to `Advanced Options > Resolution`.

If you'd rather use the GUI, open the Raspberry Pi Configuration app and select Resolution from the resultant dialog. This may help with the rendering issues.